# How to tell if a ODE system of equations is linear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I really don't understand how to find if a system is linear.

How do you tell if a system of equations is linear?

I have the following system:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = 16(y − x)$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = 45x − y − xz$

$\frac{dz}{dt} = xy − 4z$

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Did you mean $x',\ y',\ z'$ in the LHS? It's not a differential equation, otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is linear if and only if the variables $x,y,z$ enter it's rand-hand-side linearly, i.e. in the form $a(t)x+b(t)y+c(t)z$ where $a(t),b(t),c(t)$ DO NOT depend on $x,y,z$. Thus, the system in your example is not linear because it includes $xz$ in the second equation and $xy$ in the third.

In general, linear systems have the form
$$ \frac{dx}{dt}=A(t)x(t),$$
where $x$ is a vector function of time index $t$ and $A(t)$ is a matrix of coefficients that do not depend on $x$.